# Parsing an XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

Though it seems to be a very trivial question I am trying to understand XMLReader Class and it's members. Given a XML file I want to opt out of printing XML Declaration

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            String xmlString =
                    @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <!-- This is a sample XML document -->
    <Items>
      <Item>test with a child element <more/> stuff</Item>
    </Items>";
            // Create an XmlReader
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
            {
                XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
                ws.Indent = true;
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, ws))
                {

                    // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                                writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                                writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                                writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
           Console.WriteLine( output.ToString());
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

But if I comment out

```
  case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                                    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                                    break;
```

I still get to see the XML Declaration i.e.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
```

What's wrong here ?
Again if I comment out

```
 case XmlNodeType.Element:
 writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
 break;
```

it says InvalidOperationException was unhandled . 
Could you please explain ? I am not getting the whole picture.

Comment: As it is saying WriteStartElement, this is that START element which has to be there. This article might give you some better understanding. http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmlwriter-class/

Comment: Thanks but how would I not print the initial XML Declaration . Commenting out those lines do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writing of the declaration is a feature of the `XmlWriter`.  You can opt out of this using `XmlWriterSettings`.

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
     OmitXmlDeclaration = true
};

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings))
```

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) for full details of all settings available.

Answer (score 2):

Set `ws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;` in your code to omit xml declaration.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        String xmlString =
                @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!-- This is a sample XML document -->
<Items>
  <Item>test with a child element <more/> stuff</Item>
</Items>";
        // Create an XmlReader
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
        {
            XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            ws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            ws.Indent = true;
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, ws))
            {

                // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                            writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                            break;
                        //case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                        case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                            writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                            writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                            writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
       Console.WriteLine( output.ToString());
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
```